# SSH Tasks to Different Remotes with Control over them

Tags: bash, ssh, gnu-screen

I need to ssh different runs of a program to different compute nodes, namely:

- `ssh compute-1 'cd dir; ./program input1;'`
- `ssh compute-2 'cd dir; ./program input2;'`
- `ssh compute-3 ...`

I also need to:

1. have control over them (i.e., see their output to stdOut or stop them),
2. have my screen clear unless I want to see their output,
3. have them running even when I close the ssh session to the cluster.

What I am doing at the moment is to call each of them in a different `screen` session that I can detach and reattach as I want. Is there any better way to do it (e.g., that does not require opening possibly many `screen` sessions)?

Comment: `tmux` and `clusterssh`

Comment: @roaima they are not installed on the cluster I am using, and as far as I can see their installation requires `sudo` rights which I do not have.

Comment: You're running `screen` on the compute systems rather than on your local system, yes? So `ssh compute-1` then `screen` then `cd dir ; ./program input1`